# ¿Por qué me sale estos errores en mi Código de JAVA?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, stack

Tengo el siguiente código en JAVA

```
public class Radix {
    LinkedQueue[ ] digitQueue = new LinkedQueue[10]

    //APARECE ERROR for (i = 0; i < digitQueue.length; i++) {
    //APARECE ERROR digitQueue[i] = new LinkedQueue();
}

private static void distribute (int [] arr, LinkedQueue[] digitQueue,int power) {
    int i ;
    for(i = 0; i< arr.length;i++)
        digitQueue[(arr[i] / power) %10].add(arr[i]);
}

private static void collect( LinkedQueue[ ] digitQueue, int[ ] arr) {
    int i = 0, digit;

    for (digit = 0; digit < 10 ; digit++)
        while (!digitQueue[digit].isEmpty()) {
            //APARECE ERROR     arr[i] = digitQueue[digit].poll());
            i++;
        }
}

public static void radixSort(int[] arr, int d) {
    int i; 
    int power = 1;
    LinkedQueue [ ] digitQueue = new LinkedQueue[10];

    for(i=0; i<digitQueue.length; i++)
        //APARECE ERROR digitQueue[i] = new LinkedQueue();
        for (i=0; i<d; i++) {
            distribute (arr,digitQueue,power);
            collect(digitQueue,arr);
            power *=10; 
        }       
    }
}
```

Pero en las lineas marcadas me aparecen algunos errores los cuales no entiendo como se podrían solucionar y la razón por la cual están apareciendo. De igual forma tengo este otro código que complementa al que esta arriba.

```
public abstract class LinkedQueue <T> implements Queue<T> {

    private LinkedList <T> qlist = null;

    public LinkedQueue(){
        qlist = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    public T remove () {
        if(isEmpty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException("LinkedQueue pop: queue empty");
        return qlist.removeFirst();
    }

    public boolean add(T item) {
        return qlist.add(item);
    }

    public T element() {
        if(isEmpty()) 
            throw new NoSuchElementException("LinkedQueue front: queue empty");
        return qlist.getFirst();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return qlist.isEmpty();
    }

    public int size() {
        return qlist.size();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return qlist.toString();
    }

    public T poll() {
        if(isEmpty()) return null;
        return qlist.removeFirst();
    }

    public T peek() {
        if(isEmpty()) return null;
            return qlist.getFirst();
    }
}
```

Este código funciona bien, El tema que se trata es el de Stacks en JAVA, el único problema es que no entiendo cómo solucionar los errores que me aparecen en el primer código. He intentado solucionar este problema pero aun así no puedo librarme de los errores que siguen apareciendo de forma constante.

Comment: LinkedQueue<de que?>[ ] digitQueue = new LinkedQueue[10]

Answer (score 0):

Estoy viendo que tienes varios detalles en tu código. El primero es que la clase `LinkedQueue` es abstracta y no puedes instanciarla directamente, es decir, no puedes hacer:

```
digitQueue[i] = new LinkedQueue();
```

Lo que tienes que hacer en este caso es heredar esa clase en otra:

```
public class LinkedQueueExtendida extends LinkedQueue
```

e implementar los métodos que te falten: `clear(), toArray()...` etc., y esa clase es la que usarías en tu `new`:

```
digitQueue[i] = new LinkedQueueExtendida();
```

Otro detalle que encontré en tu código es que tienes que "castear" el valor que recibes de `poll()` (por cierto, tienes un paréntesis extra ahí). Tendrías que hacer algo como:

```
arr[i] = (int)digitQueue[digit].poll();
```

Por último, no tienes que forzar a que tu LinkedQueue defina explícitamente el tipo de parámetro que recibe en `T`, pero sí es recomendable.

Espero que esto te ayude.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, ya pude checar el error.